# convert XML to JSON via XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

Could you please provide XSLT code to convert from XML to JSON? I am SAP developer with zero
                knowledge in XSLT. The XSLT must be able to convert the XML to JSON format as below.I need to convert an XML source to a specified JSON format. To do this i need to remove header nodes, retain the array body and encapsulate in [ ]. I have converted the body but i am having trouble removing the header nodes and inserting the encapsulating [ ]

```
This is the XML format I receive:

            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <n0:AA_JSON_Out xmlns:n0="http://PELASEHELP.com/PI/YYY"    "namespace
                  xmlns:prx="urn:sap.com:proxy:AAA:/1SAI/TAS3DF8912DDF823A9E7198:750">
                  <root>
                        <header>
                              <id>GGG-00009</id>
                        </header>
                        <body>
                              <user_name>RAMBO</user_name>
                              <code>BBB</code>
                              <date>20190405</date>
                              <time>015553</time>
                              <timezone>GMT</timezone>
                              <mail>52170302634</mail>
                        </body>
                  </root>
                  <root>
                        <header>
                              <id>GGG-00009</id>
                        </header>
                        <body>
                              <user_name>HULK</user_name>
                              <code>UUU</code>
                              <date>20190405</date>
                              <time>015553</time>
                              <timezone>GMT</timezone>
                        </body>
                  </root>
            </n0:AA_JSON_Out>


This is what need to produce:
            [{"header":{},"body":{}},{"header":{},"body":{}}]

        Below is the output code `enter code here`result.
            [ 
               { 
                  "header":{ 
                     "id":"GGG-00009"
                  },
                  "body":{ 
                     "user_name":"RAMBO",
                     "code":"BBB",
                     "date":"20190405",
                     "time":"015553",
                     "timezone":"GMT",
                     "identfier":"52170302317"
                  }
               },
               { 
                  "header":{ 
                     "id":"GGG-00009"
                  },
                  "body":{ 
                     "user_name":"HULK",
                     "code":"UUU",
                     "date":"20190405",
                     "time":"015553",
                     "timezone":"GMT"
                  }
               }
                 ]

XSLT Code:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">[<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>]</xsl:template>

    <!-- Object or Element Property-->
    <xsl:template match="*">
            <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name()" /><xsl:if test="not(contains($childName, 'root')) and not(contains($childName, 'n0'))">"<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(name())"/>":</xsl:if><xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Array Element -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="ArrayElement">
        <xsl:call-template name="Properties"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Object Properties -->
    <xsl:template name="Properties">
        <xsl:variable name="childName" select="name()"/>
        <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="not(*|@*)">"<xsl:value-of select="."/>"</xsl:when><xsl:when test="count(*[name()=$childName]) > 1"> 

        "<xsl:value-of select="$childName"/>" :[<xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="ArrayElement"/>] </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:if test="not(contains($childName, 'root'))">{</xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/><xsl:apply-templates select="*"/><xsl:if test="not(contains($childName, 'root'))">}</xsl:if></xsl:otherwise>


        </xsl:choose>

        <xsl:if test="(contains($childName, 'body'))">}</xsl:if> 
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">,</xsl:if>


    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Attribute Property -->
    <xsl:template match="@*">"<xsl:value-of select="name()"/>" : "<xsl:value-of select="."/>",
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

    Please help me to provide XSLT code.
            Thank you,
            S,Saravannan
```

Comment: Can you show us your XSLT-Code for the body, so we can see what you already have tried.

Comment: StackOverflow is for helping with specific programming problems you encounter while programming yourself. It sadly is not for providing desired solutions.

Comment: Hi All, I have added the XSLT code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0** you can try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:n0="http://PELASEHELP.com/PI/YYY"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="n0:AA_JSON_Out">
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="root">
            <xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="header">
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:text>:{&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(id)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="id"/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text> <xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:text>},</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="body">
                <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text><xsl:text>  </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:text>:{&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="user_name"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(user_name)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="user_name"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="code"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(code)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="code"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="date"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(date)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="date"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="time"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(time)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="time"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="timezone"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(timezone)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="timezone"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="mail"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(mail)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="mail"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>}</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>    }</xsl:text><xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>,</xsl:text></xsl:if><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**DEMO** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHv

Comment: Hi Sandy. I have tried and below is the output,                  SAP-00009
                  SARAVNN
                  617
                  SAP-00010
                  SARAVNN
                  617. All the ",{} is missing.

Comment: Hi Saravannan, You can check result.

Comment: Hello Sandy, Yes it seems it is working now and I will try the full cycle process....Really appreciate your help and others help. Is there any way i should reward you..

Comment: @SaravannanSithambaram Please read the help page to inform yourself about how to properly use StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: Hello Sandy, One question. How do I add condition in this statement:    !             <xsl:if test="mail_identfier"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text><xsl:text>&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name(mail_identfier)"/><xsl:text>&quot;:&quot;</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="mail_identfier"/><xsl:text>&quot;,</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if> ! Example: if the value is 1 than local name 'XX' and if the value is 2 local name 'YY.

Comment: @SaravannanSithambaram, If you have another query please raise another question.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and will proceed to close the question.

Answer (score 4):

If you can move to XSLT 3 then you can map XML to XPath 3.1 arrays and maps that can be directly serialized as JSON:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="array { 
                       root ! 
                       map:merge(
                          * ! map { local-name() : map:merge(* ! map:entry(local-name(), string())) }
                       )
                     }"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBr

XSLT 3 is implemented for [Java](http://saxonica.com/download/java.xml), [.NET](http://saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml) and [C/C++/Python/PHP](http://saxonica.com/download/c.xml) by Saxon 9 as well as by Altova XMLSpy and Raptor.

For instance, with the new [Python API in Saxon-C 1.2.1](http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!api/saxon_c_python_api) you can use

```
import saxonc
import os

with saxonc.PySaxonProcessor() as proc:
    print(proc.version)

    xslt30_processor = proc.new_xslt30_processor()

    xslt30_processor.set_cwd(os.getcwd())

    xslt30_processor.apply_templates_returning_file(source_file = 'input-sample-to-transform-to-json1.xml', stylesheet_file = 'xml-to-xpath-31-array-and-maps-serialized-as-json1.xsl', output_file = 'example-json-output1.json')
```

to run the given stylesheet against an input sample and create a JSON result file.